# Change div background using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web page with HTML as below:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#content{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(images/loader.gif);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: #3399FF solid 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">stringname</div>
</body>
```

I have set a loader GIF as its default background. I have a PHP file, `ajax.php` which return a number (or name) with respect to a `$_POST["filename"]`. What I want is, the page send text inside the div (here `stringname`) and the AJAX will return a name or number. When the script get this data, the background URL may be changed to `return_data`.jpg (where this `return_data` is a name or number).

I think the background change script is something like:

```
var $cell = $('#content');
$cell.css('background-image', 'url(images/loader.gif)')
```

How can I do this jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $cell = $('#content');
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: { 
            filename: $("#content").html()
        },
        success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
            $cell.css("background-image", "url('/images/" + response + ".jpg')");
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

and don't forget adding the jQuery script tag to the bottom of your -body- tag (but still inside it):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi, i added a suggestion to change background... have a look at.. :)

Comment: @blasteralfred - take a look at it now, it should be just fine :) also, if you use Chrome, you could monitor the response from ajax.php in the Developer Tools, or use Firebug for Firefox. Report back if you are still having issues with this!

Comment: not working dude... :( .. can u do me a favor?? can u write a fiddle which alerts the ajax return data..

Comment: @Dvir, can u consider adding `var $cell = $('#content');` and `$cell.css('background-image', 'url(images/loader.gif)');` to your solution??

Comment: @blasteralfred: Updated the answer, and here's the jsfiddle (notice the URL is "/" there in order to not get a 404 error...): [http://jsfiddle.net/gsLZe/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/gsLZe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    ...ajax stuff...
    url : 'urlToYourPhpFile',
    data : {
        whateverTheHellYouWannaSendInAnObjectLiteralForm : true,
        floop : 'indeed'
    },
    type: 'POST, GET...',
    success: function(url) {
        ...your usual stuff
        $('#content').css('backgroundImage', url);
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: whats this ajax stuff?? I am a beginner, can u write the full code pls.. :)

Comment: @blasteralfred Edited to show a mock expression of it...visit the dock for a really detailed description with tons of examples. I don't know exactly what you want to do and how you wanna do it, so this is all I could provide.

Answer (score 0):

The below JQuery assumes that ajax.php returns exactly what you want inside of your div. If data continues many values and you only want a specific one inside of your div, say the title, consider having your ajax.php do a

```
json_encode()
```

on its return string. That will make it simple to parse and handle inside of javascript.

```
// Call this when you want to populate
$.get( 'ajax.php', function(data) {
    if( data ) {
        $("#content").html( data );
    }
} );
```